# Atajo rápido para dividir editor en 1,2,3... partes

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vscode

veréis, en sublime text existe, hay un comando que es para darle a una tecla y eligiendo 1 o 2 o 3 te divide el editor el 1/2/3 paneles diferentes.
He encontrado un comando que es CTRL + CMD + <- / -> pero esto mueve a una nueva pestaña siendo el máximo 2.

En fin, ¿Qué atajo puedo usar en Mac para dividir el editor en 3 divisiones?

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es agregar un nuevo grupo de pestañas vertical.

El atajo de teclado para hacer eso es:

**Mac**

> <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
>
> <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

---

**Windows**

> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>.

Según esta fuente: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2011/03/01/split-code-windows-vertically/, funciona para Visual Studio 2005, 2008 y 2010.

Creo que también debe funcionar en Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio Community 2015, y Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

En MacOs es `cmd+\`

En Windows es `ctrl+\`

Y si quieres modificar a tu gusto atajos de teclado, en `Archivo>Preferencias>Métodos abreviados de teclado` puedes consultar todos los atajos de teclado y editarlos.